How to add support to the beams of a small freestanding deck
I am left with a small patchwork deck which I know has not been properly done. A small part has been disassembled for remodeling work. Prior to that, parts of it were attached to the building but due to the remodeling it is now completely freestanding.
It is adjacent to the home though (acting as "patio"). Here is a picture taken from underneath the deck (note, it is not very high):


The decking will come above the the red beams (which go from right to left)
These beams currently do not have proper support closer to the building on the left side
They have support further on the right (the picture shows a pier). However, even then it can be seen that they do not have proper footings ... it's just a piece of wood resting on a concrete pad
There is a large vertical beam (in the picture going from the front to the back) which I believe is strong and has proper support from an older part of the deck (the piers with proper concrete footings can be seen in the distance)

One option is to add shim between the front-to-back beam and the left-to-right beams. Two of them currently have such shims (see picture) but it's just plywood temporarily stuffed into the gap (by the construction workers). If this is appropriate, what is the best way to attach them?
Is it necessary to add additional piers closer to the wall, for each beam? If so, what is the right way to do it? Just nailing (or screwing?) piers to the side of the beams?
Lastly, do I need to add concrete footings to the existing piers or is it fine to not touch them?
My goal is to re-assemble the deck, but doing so in the most optimal way, short of completely rebuilding it. (I will probably completely replace the deck in 5 or 10 years)

Location?  Climate?  What's the length of that cantilever?

@Huesmann California (no freezing, no snow, no rain except in winter if that’s the reason for the question). The length of the middle cantilever part (the one on the picture) is ~8ft. The entire deck is ~26ft

Asking because of frost line issues.  If you're in CA, your frost line is probably around 5", so you could conceivably simply use deck blocks (countersunk 5" at worst).  Cantilever length is the length of the overhang—I find it hard to believe that's 8' from the beam to the house.
